# Как убрать иконку загрузки telebot, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

[image: введите сюда описание]

Писал телеграмм бота и столкнулся с проблемой, как убрать флажок загрузки на кнопке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обработку нажатия необходимо добавить дополнительную строку, отвечающую за выполнение запроса **bot.answer_callback_query(c.id)**

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def ans(c):
...
    bot.answer_callback_query(c.id)
```